# Unexplained 400 error response using Terraform with Google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to create the following uptime check resource on google cloud:

```
resource "google_monitoring_uptime_check_config" "create_uptime_check" {
  display_name = "my-uptime-check"
  timeout      = "5s"
  period       = "30s"

  http_check {
    path = "/endpoint/path"
    port = "8080"
    request_method = "GET"
    accepted_response_status_codes {
      status_class = "STATUS_CLASS_2XX"
    }
  }

  monitored_resource {
    type =  "uptime_url"
    labels = {
      project_id = "${var.project_id}"
      host       = "${var.host}"
    }
  }
 
  content_matchers {
    content = "UP"
    matcher = "MATCHES_JSON_PATH"
    json_path_matcher {
      json_path = "$.status"
      json_matcher = "EXACT_MATCH"
    }
  }

  checker_type = "STATIC_IP_CHECKERS"
}
```

This is all well and good. Terraform plan green lights everything. But when I apply the changes I get back the following error response back:

```
Error: Error creating UptimeCheckConfig: googleapi: Error 400: Unable to parse 'required_content' as JSON value. Make sure to quote strings and property names.
```

I could not understand what 'required_content' means here so i enabled debug logging in terraform which prints the following request json that is generated by terraform and sent to google cloud:

```
{
  "checkerType": "STATIC_IP_CHECKERS",
  "contentMatchers": [
   {
    "content": "UP",
    "jsonPathMatcher": {
     "jsonMatcher": "EXACT_MATCH",
     "jsonPath": "$.status"
    },
    "matcher": "MATCHES_JSON_PATH"
   }
  ],
  "displayName": "my-uptime-check",
  "httpCheck": {
   "acceptedResponseStatusCodes": [
    {
     "statusClass": "STATUS_CLASS_2XX"
    }
   ],
   "path": "/endpoint/path",
   "port": 80,
   "requestMethod": "GET"
  },
  "monitoredResource": {
   "labels": {
    "host": "my.host.com",
    "project_id": "my-project-id"
   },
   "type": "uptime_url"
  },
  "period": "30s",
  "timeout": "5s"
}
```

and the response received from google cloud is:

```
{
   "error": {
     "code": 400,
     "message": "Unable to parse 'required_content' as JSON value. Make sure to quote strings and property names.",
     "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
   }
}
```

I cant seem to figure what im doing wrong. the terraform code conforms to what is in their docs. I even looked at google docs to see if im doing anything wrong but didnt find anything. Tried upgrading both terraform cli and google provider but nothing changed.

Thought about raising an issue on relevant github page but its clear from the debug logs that issue lies with google not terraform, well from what i understand at least.

Anybody got any clue what i am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you didn't specify the `content` field as a string literal by adding appropriate quotes in the `content_matchers` block.

When using json_path_matcher with `EXACT_MATCH`, you need to ensure the `content` field is identical to the response output, including all quotation marks. In JSON, string liberal is quoted. So, you should add that in your content field as: **`content = "\"UP\""`**. The following code I tested works:

```
resource "google_monitoring_uptime_check_config" "create_uptime_check" {
  display_name = "my-uptime-check"
  timeout      = "5s"
  period       = "60s"

  http_check {
    path = "/endpoint/path"
    port = "8080"
    request_method = "GET"
    accepted_response_status_codes {
      status_class = "STATUS_CLASS_2XX"
    }
  }

  monitored_resource {
    type =  "uptime_url"
    labels = {
      project_id = "${var.project_id}"
      host       = "${var.host}"
    }
  }

  content_matchers {
    content = "\"UP\""
    matcher = "MATCHES_JSON_PATH"
    json_path_matcher {
      json_path = "$.status"
      json_matcher = "EXACT_MATCH"
    }
  }

  checker_type = "STATIC_IP_CHECKERS"
}
```

You can read more about this in [Google doc](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/uptime-checks/response-validation#match-json-path-exact). Obviously, your backend needs to return the UP in response.

Comment: I saw this in one of the examples here https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/monitoring_uptime_check_config
but there are also example there without double quotes. Before this json path matcher I used CONTAIN_STRING matcher which worked fine without quotes.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with the JSON content matching section. The error message is not very helpful but it's indicating that the content matching is not parsable. Update that section of the config with escaped quotes as shown below for the content property. Specifically the `content = "\"UP\""`.

```yaml
{
  content_matchers {
    content = "\"UP\""
    matcher = "MATCHES_JSON_PATH"
    json_path_matcher {
      json_path = "$.status"
      json_matcher = "EXACT_MATCH"
    }
  }
}
```